# $(n/1+1)(n/2+1)(n/3+1)(n/4+1)....(n/n+1)<q^n$ find the smallest positive integer $q$ that satisfies the problem for all positive integer $n$

Tags: combinatorics

$$(n/1+1)(n/2+1)(n/3+1)(n/4+1)....(n/n+1)<q^n$$
Find the smallest positive integer $q$ that satisfies the problem for all positive integer $n$
I just found that problem is equivalent to 
$2n \choose n$<$q^n$

Comment: @RossMillikan The OP has written what he means, I think.  It comes out to $\binom{2n}{n}$, unless I'm very much mistaken.  If I understand you right, your interpretation would come out to $n^n/(n+1)!$ which is not bounded above by $q^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stirling's approximation gives $$\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$ so we guess that $q=4$.  This is easily show by induction.  We have $$\binom21=2<4^1$$ and the for the inductive step $$\frac{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)}\frac{n!n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)}<4$$